# Encoding percent symbol in URL creates invalid folder name on Sharepoint Group

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

i'm trying to upload file to specific non-existing path on Microsoft Sharepoint Group assuming folder hierarchy will be created based on that path. And that's true.

Problem appears when path segment have special characters. I found MS documentation stating that path segment should be encoded (using `escape` function in Javascript).

So let's say i'm uploading file `File1.txt` to a path `Test 1/Whatever%Text!Here`

Here's what url would look like:

`PUT` `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<group-id>/drive/items/root:/Test%201/Whatever%25Text%21Here:/children/File1.txt/content`

You can see encoded path segment (`/Test%201/Whatever%25Text%21Here`) and how `%` is encoded to `%25`. Seems fine to me. But this URL will create subfolder called `Whatever%25Text!Here`, not `Whatever%Text!Here`

`%25` stays `%25`, it's not decoded to `%`. Does anyone have a clue what's going on?
I was mainly testing through Microsoft Graph Api explorer, trying several different URLs, like % changing to %2525 but without luck.

Answer (score 1):

The `%` symbol is one of OneDrive for Business' "Reserved Characters".

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online):

> #### OneDrive reserved characters
>
> The following characters are OneDrive reserved characters, and can't be used in OneDrive folder and file names.
>
> ```
> onedrive-reserved  = "/" / "\" / "*" / "<" / ">" / "?" / ":" / "|"
> onedrive-business-reserved = "/" / "\" / "*" / "<" / ">" / "?" / ":" / "|" / "#" / "%"
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is, i read this doc before, and i saw that there are reserved characters. What confused me though is that i'm allowed to create folder with `%` in the name via Sharepoint without any problem. But your answer got me thinking and i've tried to create folder with other special characters via Sharepoint. I got error message saying that folder name cannot contain these `" * : < > ? / \ | .` which means `%` is allowed, and it's not working via API. So i think there's bug on Graph API. Because of that, I had to change my approach of creating folder hierarchy.

Comment: I've also tried my first approach (encoding special character in path segment) with all of the reserved characters for OneDrive Business and almost every character had different response. Here are some responses: `# = %23 = Allowed`, `* = * = Unknown Error`, `/ = %2F = allowed, but it split's folder's name into two separate folders`, `% = %25 = allowed, but folder name will be e.g. Test%251, not Test%1`, `| = %7C = Invalid request (The provided name contains invalid character '|')`, `: = %3A = Bad Request (Unsupported segment type)`, `> = %3E = Unknow Error`

Comment: Is the limitation mentioned here still in place? The [support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-onedrive-and-sharepoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa#invalidcharacters) says that `&` and `%` should now be valid for MS 365.

Comment: The support site implies this is only the case for tenants that have opted to support them. Given that limitation and the fact that the Graph documentation still lists these as reserved, I would consider it still the case.